# C# - mouse hover in taskbar, thumbnails preview is generated in window 7.

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-xp, thumbnails, taskbar

I am developing one application which shows thumbnails of running application on windows 7.
Can i achieve the same thumbnail functionality on window XP.(If I run my application on XP) 
If Yes. Then How can i achieve this.
Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 7 you can use the [Desktop Window Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (DWM) library (amongst other things) to take [screenshots / thumnails](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The documentation is part of the Win API but you can use them in C3 using platform invoke:

```
[DllImport( "dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false )]
public static extern void DwmRegisterThumbnail( IntPtr destinationWindowHandle, IntPtr sourceWindowHandle, out IntPtr thumbnailHandle );

[DllImport( "dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false )]
public static extern void DwmUnregisterThumbnail( IntPtr thumbnailHandle );

[DllImport( "dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false )]
public static extern void DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties( IntPtr thumbnailHandle, ref ThumbnailProperties properties );
```

Finally, here is [some sample code](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/05/4495.aspx) on how to implement the actual thumbnails.

Comment: @StevenHoubens i got your point. I want to know if i build this functionality, would it will work on Window XP as well.

Comment: No, this is Windows 7 and 8 only